# Remote desktop audio redirection

Tags: windows, audio, remote-access, remote-desktop

could someone help me with this?

Client(home): PC A, InputA, OutputA

Host(workstation): PC B, InputB, OutputB

I'd like to know if there is a remote desktop software(or any way to make it happen) that will allow me to connect to a remote computer and redirect PC A input to PC B input and PC B output to PC A output.

PC B receives a call, i can hear the person on my PC A, and when i speak, the person on the call through PC B can hear me.

Comment: if there is running a RDP  server over on remote PC your client can login to that remote box using the RDP client software ... I am not aware whether audio comes along for the ride